# Unflatten a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df_flat = pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8]})
```

I want to transform this dataframe, unflatten for want of a better words and transform it to a np ND array such that is looks like:

```
df_unflatten = pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'b'], 'x': [2, 6], 'y': [4, 8]}).set_index('dim1').to_numpy()
```

Edit: The 2D example was the wrong example to use here. The 3D example better highlights what i wish to do.

```
pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'dim3': ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'j'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7]})
```

which i hope to convert to a ND np array:

```
np.array([[[2, 1], [4, 3]],[[6, 5],[8, 7]]])
```

Note the extra square brackets, which gives this N levels of indexation (3 here). e.g. np.array([[[2, 1], [4, 3]],[[6, 5],[8, 7]]])[0][0][0]

I want this method to be flexible, such that if I add another dimension my 'unflattened' dataframe would become a numpy ndarray.

Are there any in built pandas functions that can help me achieve this. I am aware of functions that do the opposite e.g. .flatten() . unstack() etc. but I could not find any which achieve what I desire.

Comment: `unstack` does exactly what you need. next time, try to use it when posing the question. `df_flat.set_index(['dim1','dim2']).unstack().to_numpy()`

Comment: using unstack().to_numpy() does not do exactly what I need. Next time, try to use it when answering the question.

Comment: e.g. pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'dim3': ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'j'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7]}). unstack().to_numpy()

Comment: That's because I set the index `.set_index(['dim1','dim2'])` before I use `unstack`. In most cases, `unstack` works best when you have a multi-level index so that you can unstack across the desired level in the index. And please, try to be courteous, we are here trying to help you. Copy/pasting my solution would've also helped you ;)

Comment: `df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2', 'dim3']).unstack().to_numpy()` does not produce the desired result. It produces `array([[2, 1],[4, 3],[6, 5],[8, 7]])`, the desired result is `array([[[2, 1], [4, 3]],[[6, 5],[8, 7]]])`. I appreciate your help but if I was discourteous so were you ;)

Comment: You'll have to play around with the `level` option in the `unstack` . For example, if you want to unstack only around `dim3` then you do `df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2', 'dim3']).unstack(level=2).to_numpy()` or if you want to unstack around dim1 and dim2, then you'd do `df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2', 'dim3']).unstack(level=[1,2]).to_numpy()`. Hopefully this sets you in the right direction. Check it out [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is "unmelt" since to "melt" a DataFrame is to bring it into the form you called `df_flat`. In order to achiece said unmelting, you can to as follows:

```py
df = df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2'])['val'].unstack().reset_index()

# Output:
dim2 dim1  x  y
0       a  2  4
1       b  6  8
```

For the flexible part, you can add more dimensions in the list as parameter for `set_index`.

Comment: is the `reset_index()` really needed?

Comment: Without this the index will be set to the values of `dim1`, with `reset_index()` it will default to numeric 0-indexed values. It depends on preference and further processing of the data I'd say.

Comment: you're not wrong but it doesn't seem like the OP asked anything in particular about indexes. Moreover, because they're converting to a numpy array, doing `reset_index()` before `to_numpy()` will include the index values in the numpy matrix which is unlikely what they'd want

Comment: I'm looking for something more along the lines of `np.array([[[2, 1], [4, 3]],[[6, 5],[8, 7]]])` given then 3d example of `pd.DataFrame({'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'dim3': ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'j'], 'val': [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7]})`. Perhaps i should have used the 3D example in my question

Answer (score 0):

Given your data:

```
df_flat = pd.DataFrame({
    'dim1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'dim2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
    'val': [2, 4, 6, 8]})
df_unflatten = pd.DataFrame({
    'dim1': ['a', 'b'], 
    'x': [2, 6], 
    'y': [4, 8]}).set_index('dim1')
```

Just unstack after setting indicies. Unstack without parameters uses the last multi-index for unstacking.

```
>>> new_df = df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2']).unstack()
>>> np.allclose(new_df, df_unflatten)
True
```